# Documentation and information about linear-throughout Semantic Database Machine

Tags: database, semantics

I have to do some reaserach about this topic - LSDM, but only thing I could find is purchasable PDF in this site: [Website](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B75C7-4998V9S-S8&_user=10&_coverDate=01%2F31%2F1989&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1539343101&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=8fae0f53f2b07a86672e66dbb1222e4b&searchtype=a)

I would like to know if there is anybody willing to share this document or give some resource that can be viewed freely.

Comment: One of the things that really annoy me is people asking for _URGENT_ answers here. This is a free site - the people answering questions do not get paid for this. An answer will come when it comes.

Answer (score 0):

[Riche's list of papers](http://n1.cis.fiu.edu/publications.html) doesn't have any links to pdfs, which is usually the first place to start.

That paper's from 'Microprocessing and Microprogramming' Volume 25, Issues 1-5, January **1989**, so try your local university's library. If it's a journal they keep, they may have a paper copy.

But if it's not a really significant paper, you're unlikely to find it wild on the web if it's twenty years old.